# Possible bug with Excel for Mac 2019/2016/365: PrintOut not working under certain circumstance

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making an Excel workbook for both Windows & Mac. I have a button in my workbook that allows the user to PRINT worksheets of their choice, and another that allows them to make a PDF of worksheets of their choice.

Both buttons work perfectly on Windows. On Mac 2016/2019/365, the PDF button works fine. It’s the PRINT button that sometimes causes a problem. It doesn't work properly when the user has pressed the PDF button *before* pressing the PRINT button. In that case, the .PrintOut line of code either gives an error, or saves a PDF file instead of printing.

If I close the workbook and reopen it, it will print just fine *until* I create a PDF, and then the problem happens again. I feel like this must be a bug in Excel for Mac, but am not 100% sure. I can only test it on my one Mac computer, so I know it's possible it might have something to do with my computer.

Here is some simple code to test this.  I appreciate anyone who would try this on their Mac and let me know the results.

```
Sub PrintButton()

'this should send Sheet1 to the default printer

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").PrintOut Preview:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

End Sub

Sub PDFButton()

'this should create a PDF file of Sheet1 on the Desktop of the Mac

Dim UserName As String
Dim FileNameAndPath As String

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

UserName = MacScript("do shell script ""echo $USER""")

FileNameAndPath = "/Users/" & UserName & "/Desktop/TestPDF.pdf"

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
FileNameAndPath, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

End Sub
```

The way to test it is:

1. Run the PrintButton sub.  It should send "Sheet1" to your printer.
2. Run the PDFButton sub. It should create a PDF of "Sheet1" on your desktop.
3. Run the PrintButton sub again.  This is where the problem is happening for me. I am curious if it works properly for you, or if you receive an error?  I received Run-time 1004 error. (I have seen in some circumstances that instead of it printing the sheet here or throwing the error, it makes a PDF when it gets to the .PrintOut line.)

Comment: Hi Ken.  I have updated my question.  Please let me know if this is acceptable.

Comment: Much better. I've voted to reopen your question.

Comment: Ken, I see that my question has a score of -2. Is there something wrong with it in it's current form, or is the -2 from back before I made the fixes yesterday?  I am worried that the negative score is stopping people from reading it.  I see it has only been viewed 23 times so far.

Comment: Looks good to me. I've upvoted it (meant to after it was reopened, but hadn't stopped back by until now). That should help with the vote count. :-)